# What is the easiest way to calculate the q-expansion of the j-invariant?

Tags: modular-forms

The [j-invaraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) has a q-series. What is the easiest way to compute this series?

This is the way I currently know how to do it. Using Maxima:

```
a(k):=coeff(q*taylor(12^3/(1-(1-504*sum(n^5*q^n/(1-q^n),n,1,inf))^2/(1+240*sum(n^3*q^n/(1-q^n),n,1,inf))^3),q,0,k),q,k)
```

Which is from the formula:

$$j(q) = \frac{12^3}{1-\frac{\left(1-504 \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^3\frac{ q^n}{1-q^n}\right)^2}{\left(1+240\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^5\frac{ q^n}{1-q^n}\right)^3}} = \frac{1}{q}+744+198884q+... = \frac{1}{q}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a(k) q^n$$

Which is basically just expanded.  Where $a(k)$ gives the $k^{th}$ coefficient.

This formula gives me:

```
[1,744,196884,21493760,864299970,20245856256,333202640600,4252023300096,44656994071935,401490886656000,3176440229784420]
```

Surely there must be a simpler formula? (Just using elementary functions). I suppose one could just  expand the above series and get a formula in terms of sums of binomial coefficients.

This one (slightly shorter) also works:

```
a(k):=coeff(taylor((1+240*sum(n^3*q^n/(1-q^n),n,1,inf))^3*prod( (1-q^n)^(-24),n,1,inf),q,0,k),q,k);
```

(I'd like to know how internally the software works these out!)

Comment: That depends of what you have available. You have several choices in the [OEIS sequence A000521](https://oeis.org/A000521) entry and there are other ways.

Comment: @Somos Thanks I'll take a look

Comment: Some approaches are described in [Baier, Köhler 2003: How to Compute the Coefficients of the Elliptic Modular Function $j(z)$](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10586458.2003.10504716). The winner seems to have been a method described in: Masanobu Kaneko, Traces of singular moduli and the Fourier coefficients of the elliptic modular function $j(\tau)$, CRM Proceedings and Lecture Notes, vol. 19, 1999.04.